# Combine two strings and remove duplicate characters

Tags: string, bash, duplicates

I have 2 strings and I want to combine them and remove duplicates.

Example:

```
a=abcdefghijkl
b=dfg
```

then combining them should yield

```
c=dfgabcehijkl
```

where the value of `b` is provided by the user. How can I do this?

Comment: How should the order of the final string be determined? How do you want to treat multiple duplicates?

Comment: thanks for editing, im new here.

the sorting should be the string b must be in front of the string a. multiple duplicates must be eliminated too. currently im looking into cut option and still learning it

Comment: I figured you want to delete multiple characters, is that true or do you want to delete multiple substrings?

Comment: yea right. i want to delete multiple char. btw string a is fixed. user enter string b, combines b and a and deletes duplicated in a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `sed`. You can do this in pure bash:

```
a=abcdefghijkl
b=dfg
c="$b${a//[$b]/}"
echo "$c"
```

This uses the built-in string substitution capabilities of bash to do a global replacement on `$a`, removing all characters that are in `$b`.
Output:

```
dfgabcehijkl
```

Comment: i tried your code. it works, but as soon as i changed it so that user can input for $b, then the output simple gives the $b and $a. theres no change at all

Comment: I have modified the code slightly, does it work now? Can you  edit your question to show how you are reading in the value of `$b` and give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: it seems like logical error on my code on requesting user input. i solved it and it giving out correct input, thanks a lot Mr Tom. ill edit my post and the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
c="${b}$(echo "${a}" | sed "s/[${b}]//g")"
```

Comment: +1 nice. or shorter `echo $b$(sed "s/[$b]//g"<<<"$a")`

Comment: @SharfudinMohdIbrahim do you have any special characters in a or b except for letters?

Comment: @martin no special char. only letters

Comment: my guess is that your `b` is empty. (if I don't set `b` I get that exact error).

Comment: indeed. at first the string is empty. i call a simple echo to indicate for user to input and i read $b. and then i get the error

Comment: I think that there's a problem with the way you're reading to b. it explains the problems you're seeing when testing both answers. Also, I think that @TomFenech 's answer is a little better because bash replacement is a little lighter than sed + it works fine in case b is empty. I'm leaving this answer for comparison purposes and for the credit. :)